# How to set default APT source

Tags: apt

Running `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf` gives:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

I thought doing that would disallow the command `apt-get install wajig` to work, if a newer version was available anywhere but **Stable**.

How do I set up APT so that such a version would require me to specify the repository name in order to install it (e.g. `apt-get --target-release testing wajig`)?

[**update**] I wasn't aware that my question wasn't so clear. I want this to be an archive-wide setting (i.e. it should apply to each package in the Stable archive), not to some specific package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your "**/etc/apt/preferences**":

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

This is from `man apt_preferences` where `P` means `Pin-Priority`:

```
500 < P <=990
   causes a version to be installed unless there is a version available belonging to the target release or the installed version is more recent

P < 0
   prevents the version from being installed
```

See [this Debian wiki page](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) for something gentler than the manpage.

Comment: You can replace "wajig" with *

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `wajig` package with a positive [pin priority](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) in any of your sources, `apt-get install wajig` will install it. `Default-Release` works like setting a high priority to that particular release. If I understand correctly, you'd like `apt-get install wajig` to work if squeeze has the latest version and not to work otherwise; I don't think that's possible.